# How to avoid cumbersome holder in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have to deal with the following java code

```
abstract class ScriptResult {
    void ifSuccess(Consumer<Object> block) {
    }

    void ifError(Consumer<Throwable> block) {
    }

    static class Success extends ScriptResult {
        private final Object returnValue;

        Success(Object returnValue) {
            this.returnValue = returnValue;
        }

        @Override
        void ifSuccess(Consumer<Object> block) {
            block.accept(returnValue);
        }
    }

    static class Error extends ScriptResult {
        private final Throwable throwable;

        Error(Throwable throwable) {
            this.throwable = throwable;
        }

        @Override
        void ifError(Consumer<Throwable> block) {
            block.accept(throwable);
        }
    }
}
```

My kotlin tests make use of the following assertion helper:

```
private lateinit var scriptResult: ScriptResult

inline fun <reified T : Throwable> shouldHaveThrown(): T {
    scriptResult.ifSuccess { result ->
        fail("should have thrown ${T::class.java.name}, but returned `$result´")
    }
    lateinit var holder: T // (1)
    scriptResult.ifError { throwable ->
        if (throwable is T) {
            holder = throwable // (2)
        } else {
            fail("expected ${T::class.java.name} to be thrown, but threw `$throwable´")
        }
    }
    return holder // (3)
}
```

The assertion helper is effective. I can use it like so:

```
    val thrown = execution.shouldHaveThrown<MissingMethodException>()
    assertThat(thrown.message).contains("missedMethod")
```

But I suspect there is a more idiomatic way to return `throwable` from `shouldHaveThrown`, then to (1) declaring a holder, (2) assigning it and (3) eventually returning it. How?

Comment: why is it even a list?

Comment: Is Java code changeable? I see another ways: use `return@shouldHaveThrown` at (2) and `fail` at (3), or use `lateinit`, but they are still hacks. And I don't think there is a clean way, since the compiler has no way to know if either `ifSuccess` or `ifError` will execute their blocks.

Comment: @TimCastelijns of course you're wright. No need for a list. I updated the question